# Are global variables anti-pattern in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that changes highlighting on a grid as the mouse is dragged across.

```
public handleDragMove = (e: any) => {
    if (this.props.highlightActive) {
        const rindex: number = e.currentTarget.parentNode.rowIndex;
        const cindex: number = e.currentTarget.cellIndex;

        const grid = {
            rowIndex: rindex,
            cellIndex: cindex,
        };
        if (rindex !== this.state.grid.rowIndex && cindex !== this.state.grid.cellIndex){              
                if (e.target.style.backgroundColor === 'blue') {
                    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                }
                else {
                    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
                }
                this.setState({
                    gridData: gridData
                });
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I have tried using  `setState`, however it does not update anywhere fast enough for my use. By the time the state is updated, there are 20 something calls to update the state as a result of the drag event. The cells thus flicker rapidly as the mouse is moved across the cells.

For this sort of situation, is it anti-pattern to have a variable that is simply updated with the coordinates in a synchronous fashion? I have tried coming up with a method of using callbacks and I can't seem to get an asynchronous solution to work.

Comment: Could you move the logic of what to update inside the handledrag function? so you don't even have to use useState()? or rather use useState() to set the component that should be highlighted

Comment: If your state has NO side effects in your render output then you probably shouldn't be using state. You could just set it into your class instance, like `this.gridData = {}`

Comment: [The React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state) back up what @enapupe says: "If some value isn’t used for rendering or data flow (for example, a timer ID), you don’t have to put it in the state. Such values can be defined as fields on the component instance."

Comment: Ultimately I do want to capture the highlighting for a database, however I am unsure how to incorporate the state. It's about a 20 x 40 grid. It just seemed really inefficient to me to check and update such a large matrix in the state each time, as opposed to doing it when the drag is over.

Comment: Define "capture the highlighting". If this is a UI feature then you probably want to debounce it. What are you actually moving? Do you need to capture the entire move sequence, or just the drag-start and drag-release?

Comment: For simplicity let's assume a 5x5 table. The user is able to drag their mouse across cells and highlight them, such that if they drag from 0,3 to 4,3, it will update the database that cells 0,3; 1,3; 2,3; 4,3 have all been highlighted. The user can do the opposite and remove highlight in the same fashion. The moves also do not need to be linear.